# App getting close whenever i open my window 8.1 app from different another app using c#?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I added extension in app manifest

I added protocol name open

And launch from app2

by launcher

await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("open://useLess?GetPage2"), options);

App is launching but after few seconds it will close automatically

Comment: According to your description, it seems you don't miss anything. Could your app be opened normally if you don't use app launcher? And what your `options` refer to? It seems you want to navigate to `Page2` directly.

Comment: Yes Mattew, As i declare port name open to access and open page2 if i pass GetPage2 value. it will open correctly but in few second it will close automaticaly.